# cut matched pattern from column

Tags: mysql

i have bunch of rows containing `http://www.domainname.com`
i need to update those so `http://` part is gone
how to do this elegantly within one query execution??

e.g. table 'video', column in question 'url'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
UPDATE `video` SET `url` = REPLACE(`url`,"http://","")
```

Comment: foreign key constraint is making me problems. i am trying to delete it with: alter table favorite drop foreign key(fav_url) but get:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: i think u must set *unique key* index on `url` bcoz #1064 is duplicate entry error

Answer (score 0):

First execute the query below to ensure that the output is as expected

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(url,  8) as url FROM video;
```

If you are satisfied execute

```
UPDATE video SET url = SUBSTRING(url,  8);
```